# Tooltip is not working on a html image

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have a html image, on hover of which a tooltip should be displayed.The text of the tooltip is dynamically set based on some model attributes.But, as I hover , the hover function is getting executed, but I am not able to see the tooltip of the same.Below is the code.

```
  $('#img2').hover(function(){
  console.log("on hover image2");
  var oldregion=null;var newregion=null;var startdate=null;
  oldregion=${oldregion};
  newregion=${newregion};
  startdate=${startdate};
  document.getElementById('img2').title='Location changed from '+ '${oldregion}' +' to '+ '${newregion}' +' on '+ '${startdate}';   
  });
```

It is printing "on hover image2", but the "Location changed from..." text that should appear as tooltip is not displayed.${oldregion},${newregion},${startdate} are the model attributes coming from the spring controller and its values are coming corrrectly.But, the tooltip is not shown with that dynamic text.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip is probably **behind** the image. Make sure the image is a JLabel, since tooltips work on JLabels. The way you can get around this issue is by using a glass pane. You can read about one [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) Basically it makes it so that the image is behind a little virtual glass, and you can hover your mouse over it, and the tooltip will display above the pane.

```
JPanel glass = ((JPanel) imagejlabelname.getGlassPane()); //Glasspane
    glass.setVisible(true);
```

Now, if you want to have interaction on the image and the tooltip to display only on some of the image, make sure to put the image in a JPanel, and size it accordingly. Then, you can add a mouse listener to that specific part of the JPanel.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {

**Inherited classes go here unless abstract**

}
```

Basically, you have multiple ways of doing this. If you want to have a quick tooltip that will display as soon as you place it on the image, you should use my second method, mouse listener.

~Rich

Comment: Hi Rich, I am using JSP and html in the front end.So, I cannot use JPanel and mouseMoved events. Is there anything I can do in JSP and html? Thanks,Poorna.

Comment: I am not familiar with JSP, but try this:

Comment: Execute a JavaScript when moving the mouse pointer over a <div> element:

<div onmousemove="myFunction()">Move the cursor over me</div>

Comment: And just use a simple container instead of a JPanel and JLabel.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich.I tried onmousemove event and it worked.

Comment: @Poorna Murali Glad I could help! Make sure to mark this answer as best answer if it helped (the little check button under the like button) :) Good luck, and feel free to ask more questions, i'll be happy to answer! ~Rich